# фоновая картинка с блоком внутри

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

есть внешний  блок с  фоновой  картинкой  на весь блок а внутри него  блок с контентом

2 вопроса

как переместить этот блок с контентом  так как мне нужно - почему- то все смещается вместе с фоном

и еще как сделать так чтобы остальная часть листвы бамбука была видна

сайт http://frontend-er.h1n.ru/asia-spa/
[image: картинка пояснения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По первому вопросу: для блока `.services__wrapper` пропишите `background-position: top center;`

По второму: для блока `.block-intro-bambuk` установите нужный вам отступ `padding`.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы при уменьшении экрана бамбук не пропадал

Comment: работает - но теперь уже контент наезжает на бамбук :)